# Rotation matrix in 2D Asteroid shooting

Tags: rotations, trigonometric-series

I got stuck solving this Asteroid shooting game. The game is described as follows:

A ship is moving and trying to shoot asteroids in a 2D plane. The ship has a 360-degree ring sensor that can sense an asteroid (will give range and bearing measurements). This picture shows what I mean:
[image]
Let $\beta$ be a shooting angle. Asteroid's diameter is 3 meters. We do not know the ship's motions. Asteroids move with constant velocity. Given a ship's pose and an asteroid's positions (relative to a fixed frame), calculate $\beta$ in the ship's frame.

This seems to be simple. We transform from the fixed frame to the ship's frame using the ship's pose and then calculate the bearing of the asteroid in the ship's frame. However, the results do not checkout with the ground truths. The following table shows the ground truth measurement including the ship's poses, asteroid's positions, and correct shooting angles.

```
No|          Ship                                ||           Asteroid            || check shot
  |x(m)   | y(m)  | vx(m/s)| vy(m/s)|heading(rad)|| x(m)  | y(m)  |vx(m/s)|vy(m/s)||Min(rad)| Max(rad)
1 |411.542|421.371|6.919   |1.402   |-1.402      ||313.626|373.795|7.802  |1.780  ||-1.2999 | -1.2724
2 |385.232|395.177|-0.784  |-1.626  |-2.792      ||400.358|412.789|1.636  |-2.61  ||-2.7772 | -2.6487
3 |227.302|391.359|-5.638  |-1.819  |0.008       ||481.877|282.792|1.636  |-2.61  ||-0.3459 | -0.3351
4 |382.034|376.118|-4.236  |8.931   |2.692       ||458.633|319.859|1.636  |-2.61  || 2.747  |  2.7786
5 |377.154|375.831|5.868   |-10.205 |1.492       ||447.502|337.611|1.636  |-2.61  ||-1.8522 | -1.8147
```

For example, the calculated bearing in the ship's frame given the information in row 3 is -0.4031, which does not agree with the provided ground truth.

I am not sure what I have overlooked and/or misunderstood that gives me the wrong results. I greatly appreciate any hints.

EDIT1. I forgot to include that one can fire at any angle around the ship.

Comment: I didn't go through the numerical values (and I don't know how they were calculated!) but I would start like this: Let the ship be in the origin, and the asteroid is at $(x_0, y_0)$ and has radius $R$. Now, the angle to the centre of the asteroid (not taking into account the orientation of the ship) can be calculated from
$$
\tan \alpha = \frac{y_0}{x_0}
$$
The distance to the centre of the asteroid is
$$
d = \sqrt{  x_0^2 + y_0^2 }
$$
And finally, the "half-angle" of the check shot is
$$
\sin \alpha_1 = \frac{R}{d}
$$
Was this how you derived the equations? Or how?

Comment: @MattiP. yes, it is almost exactly what I've done to get the shooting angle. Since the ground truths are given in a fixed frame, "let the ship be the origin" is equivalent to perform a transformation from that fixed frame to the ship's frame. After the transform, everything is the same as you laid out. Now I don't know how the values of check shot are calculated, because they are given as ground truths.

Comment: You said that not taking into account the ship's heading gives you those equations, can you help me understand how to incorporate the ship's heading into those equations? Oh, and I forgot to include that you can fire at any angle around the ship. Will edit my question.